# List the files with latest data

Tags: shell, date, unix

I was trying to get a list of files with latest data in a day. The day can be found from the file name.

Input files of type `abc_YYYYMMDDHH24MISS.txt`

```
abc_20230101033006.txt  
abc_20230101043006.txt
abc_20230102033006.txt  
abc_20230102043006.txt

expected output 
abc_20230101043006.txt
abc_20230102043006.txt
```

I have tried this command

```
ls | cut -b 1-12|uniq |ls |sort|tail -1
```

result :(getting only one file)

```
abc_20230102043006.txt
```

Comment: Based on filenames or last modification date?

Comment: based on file names( last modified date can be found in the file name pattern)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
$ ls -1
abc_20230101033006.txt
abc_20230101043006.txt
abc_20230102033006.txt
abc_20230102043006.txt
```

```
$ printf '%s\n' abc_* |
    awk '{k=substr($0, 0,12);a[k]=$0}END{for (i in a) print a[i]}'

abc_20230101043006.txt
abc_20230102043006.txt
```

Comment: You doubted? =)